# Load Pre-trained model in Pytorch

Tags: python-2.7, pytorch, pre-trained-model

I am currently working on GANS, I have downloaded the code and models from http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~vondrick/tinyvideo/, where I just need to run to get output. I have given paths and all correctly, and the code where i am receiving an error is shown below. The have wrote the lines correctly but still getting syntax error. Please help me!

```
import torch

import torch.legacy.nn

import torchfile

from skimage import io, transform

import torch.nn as nn

import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn

cudnn.enabled = True

opt = {
  model = 'models/beach/iter63000_net.t7',
  batchSize = 128,
  gpu = 1,
  cudnn = 1,
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you are trying to init a python [dictionary](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/how-to-use-dictionaries-in-python/). this is how you do it:

```
opt = {
  'model': 'models/beach/iter63000_net.t7',
  'batchSize': 128,
  'gpu':  1,
  'cudnn': 1,
}
```

Comment: thanks, i got it. can you help me in this line                                                                    'local noise = torch.Tensor(opt.batchSize, 100):normal():cuda()'

Comment: @Rajesh it seems like you are trying to run [torch](http://torch.ch/) (as opposed to **pytorch**) code. Check pytorch support for [legacy](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.0/legacy.html) models for more information.